# Typescript: delete key from object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to delete a key from an object in Typescript.

The Object is coming from firestore. FriendID is a var (string);

```
userObj = getDocument.data()['friendsObj'];
delete userObj[friendID];
```

In previous code, I checked if userMap 'contains' the friendID. If that's the case I use this code. But I get the error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Map<any, any>'.
```

Is it because it doesn't now the exact value of the userMap and friendID?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Example friendsID: "1KDL8932"

Example userObj: { K79DFS: 'Bob', 1KDL8932: 'Jeff'}

Comment: What is the type/interface for `userObj`? Looks like it does not have an index. What is the type of `friendID`?

Comment: I updated the answer with examples.

Comment: I mean, how do you declare the type for `userObject`?

Comment: Ow  now I see, I declared it incorrectly, thanks for the help!